# Dot-files and other meta data on non-Mac network shares

Tags: finder, smb

Is there a way to tell Finder to not use (or worry about) the ._* files and other meta-data files it normally tries to use when it's on a network share?

Currently when I'm in Finder and I try to copy a file to a network share it results in an error:

> The Finder can’t complete the
>   operation because some data in “file_name” can’t be read or written.
>   (Error code -36)

But I can copy the file from the terminal command line to the network share and use it from Finder afterward just fine.  It seems that the meta-data isn't really needed on the network share.  Is there a way to tell Finder this?

For reference, I'm using Snow Leopard and the share is a Samba share on a Linux server.

Comment: Similar: [Why are dot underscore ._ files created, and how can I avoid them?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14980/8546) (2011), I answered the more recent question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is the file you're trying to copy using a resource fork?

If you're dealing with `.DS_Store` file issues run the following command in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

If you're having issues with resource forks on Snow Leopard you may need to change your settings for the streams setting in `smb.conf` on the Linux machine or `nsmb.conf` on your local Mac. (`._FILENAME` files are the resource forks of the file). Check out [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/141944/mac-os-x-10-6-clients-cannot-see-resource-fork-files-on-a-cifs-network-share) for more details on this.

Comment: @Josh K: It didn't even notify me that you had answered.

Comment: Didn't do the trick.  I had high hopes for that Super User suggestion as well, but it didn't work either :(  It's definitely the resource forks, and I've tried creating that local nsmb.conf file (even rebooted just to make sure) but the error persists.  It still creates the ._ file on the server and throws the same error, leaving a data file of zero bytes.

Comment: @David: Any chance of knowing if it works with Leopard? You can also try using veto_files on the server which is sometimes the cure and other times the cause of issues with Finder. (http://serverfault.com/questions/15044/preventing-mac-os-x-clients-from-polluting-windows-shares-with-resource-forks/15437#15437)

Comment: No idea on 10.5, sorry.  I've tried veto files, tried stuff here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4017  No dice yet.  There are multiple causes for this generic Finder I/O error, but so far I haven't found a solution for mine.

Answer (score 3):

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

Will get rid of the DS files. Anything else you might have to do by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Adapted from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57832/8546

---

## Finder

Finder does much to ensure integrity of data, and to make its results compatible with a broad range of Apple operating systems. For some types of copy/move routines, `._` (dot underscore) files are **required**.

## File system

If creation of `._` files is prevented at the file system level, then that file system is partially incompatible with at least:

- Apple Finder
- Microsoft Office Excel, PowerPoint and Word 2011.

(For any use case that involves Office 2011 saving to a file system, you must allow `._` on that file system … and so on.)

## Error code -36

-36 (ioErr) (I/O error) is a file system error, it indicates that data cannot be sent or received by the operating system. Historically, [errors of this type were bummers](http://web.archive.org/web/20100827221247/http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1618?).

Without knowing the detail of your Samba configuration:

- I guess that in your case, error -36 is the result of a file system restriction.

---

For more detail please see my answer to an older question, [Why are dot underscore ._ files created, and how can I avoid them?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14980/8546):

- [Purposes of .DS_Store and ._ files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51147/8546)

Answer (score 0):

This is not working for me anymore.
So i have added ._* to the **veto files**
I think it's works but i don't know if it has other complications?

**vi /etc/samba/smb.conf**

**[global]
veto files = /._*/.AppleDB/.AppleDouble/.AppleDesktop/:2eDS_Store/Network Trash Folder/Temporary Items/TheVolumeSettingsFolder/.@_*thumb/.@*_desc/:2e*/**

**(esc-shift-ZZ)
service smb restart
service nmb restart**

Comment: You can also run this in the cron<br>
find . -type f -name "._*" -exec rm -rvf {} +;