# How to disable ._ AppleDouble files for SMB?

Tags: macos, finder, smb

I have a small problem. I don't want that our Macs here create the `._` files to the network drive. For example when you copy an image over the finder to the SMB storage.

Is there a way to disable this function in Finder?

The `.DS_Store` file is already disabled, but not files such as `._pic1.jpg` .

We activated veto files in samba to prevent creation of `._` files, there arose an error – not enough permissions on the drive.

Thank to all ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stop OS X from writing Spotlight and Trash files to memory cards and USB sticks?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6707/how-do-i-stop-os-x-from-writing-spotlight-and-trash-files-to-memory-cards-and-usb)

Comment: More recent, with an accepted answer: [Prevent Apple Double Format Files on Remote Share/Disk](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/20389/8546)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Finder

Finder does much to ensure integrity of data, and to make its results compatible with a broad range of Apple operating systems.

Please, you should **not attempt to prevent Finder** from creating `._` (dot underscore) files during copy or move routines.

## File system

If you prevent creation at the file system level – as you did with your configuration of Samba – you make that file system partially incompatible with at least:

- Apple Finder
- Microsoft Office Excel, PowerPoint and Word 2011.

(For any use case that involves Office 2011 saving to a file system, you must allow `._` on that file system … and so on.)

---

For more detail please see my answer to a more recent question, [Why are dot underscore ._ files created, and how can I avoid them?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14980/8546):

- [Purposes of .DS_Store and ._ files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51147/8546)

Comment: Thx. The post is a bit older and there is no way to prevent it. I have made a script which delete this files.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know of a way within Finder, but Blue Harvest (paid application) offers this functionality: http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest4/