# Prevent Apple Double Format Files on Remote Share/Disk

Tags: file-transfer, macos

I have a web application on a local Linux Apache server that scans a folder for new files and then processes them.

I have an SMB share to this folder and I use Path Finder to copy files over from my Mac (10.6).

The problem is that when I copy files over a whole lot of "._filename" resource fork files get created on the share and then the web application gets confused when it encounters them. I could fix the web application to be a bit smarter and ignore them, but this is also annoying when archiving and copying to external drives.

I have managed to turn off .DS_Store files and I did see a similar question with an answer, but it seemed to be dealing with NTFS Streams and a nsmb.conf file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an application called BlueHarvest that fully automates the clean up of these files.

http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest4/

Alternatively, you can use terminal:

cp -X /sourcedirectory/ /volumes/destinationsmbshare/

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57832/8546

---

## Finder

Finder does much to ensure integrity of data, and to make its results compatible with a broad range of Apple operating systems. For some types of copy/move routines, `._` (dot underscore) files are **required**.

## File system

If you prevent creation of `._` files at the file system level, you make that file system partially incompatible with at least:

- Apple Finder
- Microsoft Office Excel, PowerPoint and Word 2011.

(For any use case that involves Office 2011 saving to a file system, you must allow `._` on that file system … and so on.)

---

For more detail please see my answer to an older question, [Why are dot underscore ._ files created, and how can I avoid them?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14980/8546):

- [Purposes of .DS_Store and ._ files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51147/8546)